# Does AnyOne Know how to Debug SharePointPnP.PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp

I am using VS2017.

I have downloaded into the same level, but diferent directories, in my GitHub Repro, SharePointPnP.PowerShell and OfficeDevPnP.Core and compiled both in Debug Mode.

I have attached to all of the PowerShell processes I can find.

I have put breakpoints in GetFeature.cs and PnPWebRetrievalsCmdlet.cs.

I have run `Get-PnPFeature -Scope Web -Web https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/collaboration`

The above command fails "File Not Found" but no breakpoints were hit.

I repeat with command `Get-PnPFeature -Scope Web -Web Collaboration`.

This command works but still no breakpoints hit.

Have I missed anything ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy your build output into the Program Files directory for the module version you have installed, usually found here: `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`

That should make the runtime to load the Debug versions you compiled, and the debug symbols to be available. You might have to fudge the version number in AssemblyInfo.cs to match whatever's currently installed.

Mind and close all PowerShell windows first, to unlink the DLLs.

EDIT: Alternatively, uninstall the PnP you have installed the normal way, and use `Import-Module` to install the copy that's in your build output. Then attempt the attach-debug method.